# Unable to find Nuget package "entityframework"

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I am pretty new to EF and have tried to install `entityframework` from the Package Manager console. But I get this error:

```
PM> install-package entityframework
install-package : Unable to find package 'entityframework'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package entityframework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Not sure why I am getting this error.

This is my settings for Package Source;

[image]

Is the Package Source setup correctly, if it is, what is the issue with installing EF?

Please advise.

Comment: Can you install other packages? Also, can you install anything via the `Manage NuGet packages...` window (just right click on the project in Solution Explorer)?

Comment: Do you have the name of some test package I should try?

Comment: Doesn't matter, try NewtonSoft.Json. Just to see if the issue is with EF only or with the connection to NuGet in general.

Comment: Yes, I can install json

Comment: @user1205746, Make sure your internet connection is ok.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try updating your NuGet package Manager (via `Tools` -> `Extensions and updates` and then add a new feed with https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json as source.

**UPDATE**

NuGet Package Manager
Go to `Tools` -> `Extensions and updates`, in the popup, select the `Updates` -> `Visual Studio Gallery` submenu. Check if NuGet is listed there. If so, update it.

Adding a new NuGet feed
Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Package sources`. Click on the green plus icon to add a new source. You can enter any name you want (e.g. nuget.org) and enter `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` as source.

After this is done, in `Package Manager Console`, you'll see the newly created entry in the dropdown  `Package source`.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. Could you please elaborate what you meant by adding a new feed? Replacing the existing Package Sources with the url you mentioned above? I went in extensions and updates, and was told Nuget Package Manager already existed, I only have the option to remove it.

Comment: See me comment with the extended description.

Comment: Thanks Szeki. Adding the new feed in Tools->Option works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check what Package source is selected in the Package source list
[image]

make sure that nuget.org is selected

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting Visual Studio worked for me (for some reason).